# Macro to Create Separate Word Page for Each Row in Excel Document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Goal: create a separate Word page (can all be in the same Word doc) for each row in my Excel document.

Row 1 contains questions and Rows 2-n contain people's responses. Here's what I would like as an output:

```
Page 1 of Word Doc:

A1 Question

A2 Answer

B1 Question

B2 Answer

etc.

Page 2 of Word Doc:


A1 Question


A3 Answer


B1 Question


B3 Answer

etc.
```

If it's possible to have the questions (all of Row 1) bolded in the Word output, that would be fantastic!

Here's the code I'm working with now.

```
Sub WordDoc()
Dim TextEnter As String
Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim wordApp As Object
Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application") 'Takes the object wordApp and assigns it as a Microsoft Word application
wordApp.Visible = True 'Word application is visible

'Adds a new document to the application
wordApp.Documents.Add _
Template:="", _
NewTemplate:=False

RowNum = 1

'Loop continues until a blank line is read; can be edited as necessary
Do While Range("A" & RowNum).Text <> ""
    TextEnter = Range("A" & RowNum).Text & " " & Range("B" & RowNum).Text & " " & Range("C" & RowNum).Text & " " & Range("D" & RowNum).Text & " " & Range("E" & RowNum).Text & " " & Range("F" & RowNum).Text & " " & Range("G" & RowNum).Text & " " & Range("H" & RowNum).Text
    'Puts text of row into a string adjust to the number of columns by adding more range
    wordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph 'Moves to the next line in word doc
    wordApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextEnter 'Enters Text to document
    RowNum = RowNum + 1 'Increments to the next row
Loop
End Sub
```

Problems with current code:

1. I need Row 1 to be repeated for each response. The code, as it is now, just bundles the row's information together into a paragraph.
2. I would like the code to be dynamic and loop through however many columns there are, without having to define each column.
3. I would like each response to be on a separate page in the Word doc.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @Chrismas007 posted code in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noted what my code does inline.

```
Sub WordDoc()
    Dim TextEnter As String
    Dim RowNum As Integer
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim LastRow, LastCol, CurRow, CurCol As Long

    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application") 'Takes the object wordApp and assigns it as a Microsoft Word application
    wordApp.Visible = True 'Word application is visible

    'Adds a new document to the application
    wordApp.Documents.Add _
    Template:="", _
    NewTemplate:=False

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'For... Next Loop through all rows
    For CurRow = 2 To LastRow
        TextEnter = ""
        'For... Next Loop to combine all columns (header and answer) for given row into string
        For CurCol = 1 To LastCol
            TextEnter = TextEnter & Cells(1, CurCol).Value & vbCrLf & Cells(CurRow, CurCol).Value & vbCrLf
        Next CurCol
        wordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph 'Moves to the next line in word doc
        wordApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=TextEnter 'Enters Text to document
        wordApp.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=7 ' wdPageBreak
    Next CurRow

End Sub
```